# How to reuse Spring Kafka code to setup multiple listeners?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

If my application has one listener, the case is dead simple:

I will configure `spring.kafka.*`, Spring Boot will parse the configuration to `KafkaPropeties` and initialize all required beans.

But I have two listeners, let say one saves records to file and second to database. I would like reuse as much as possible Spring Boot conventions.

I would like to configure `file.kafka.*` and `db.kafka.*`, parse these configuration to 2 `KafkaProperties` beans:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("file.kafka")
@Bean(autowireCandidate = false)
KafkaProperties fileKafkaProperties() {
  return new KafkaProperties();
}

@ConfigurationProperties("db.kafka")
@Bean(autowireCandidate = false)
KafkaProperties dbKafkaProperties() {
  return new KafkaProperties();
}
```

and finally create 2 `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`: db and file, respectively.

The problem is that to apply `KafkaPropeties` to `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` I need `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer`. But the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` is not enough public to be initialized with  `KafkaPropeties`.

Is there a public access limitation problem on ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer or do I something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From [KafkaProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.html#buildConsumerProperties--) you can build `ConsumerFactory`

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name="kafkaConsumerFactory")
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
        new StringDeserializer(),
        new StringDeserializer());
}
```

Use [ConsumerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/ConsumerFactory.html) to build [ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.html)

```
@Bean
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
                kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
factory.setConcurrency(3);
factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
return factory;
}
```

Comment: I do exactly as you show, but the disgust is that I can configure ConsumerFactory with `file.kafka.consumer.*` but I can't configure ListenerContainerFactory with `file.kafka.listener.*`